# How to get full file path to rendered image?

Tags: python, scripting, path

I need to get full, absolute path to the image that has been rendered. Unfortunately `bpy.path.abspath()` returns only the folder path and not the disk. Same with all the other path functions - no disk.

Comment: Could it be something like 
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"), bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)). I'm just no sure of what you get with that function alone.

Comment: Your code appends the D disk to the path (probably because my Blender is running from D) instead of C, to which the render is saved (specifically to `C:\tmp\render.png`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a utility function:

> frame_path()
>   RenderSettings.frame_path(frame=1)
>   Return the absolute path to the filename to be written for a given frame

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
path = scene.render.frame_path(scene.frame_current)
```

Comment: Still not 100% correct. For some reason shows me a slightly different file name. My script generates a render filename and then puts it in `bpy.context.scene.render.filepath` (just before rendering). The name contains a "#" but when I call `scene.render.frame_path(scene.frame_current)`, it changes the "#" to "1" for some reason. But at least, I guess, I can get the folder path (with the disk) and then manually append the filename. Will try that

Comment: Blender fills in '#' in the output filename with the frame number that was rendered. To get a specific file you will need to know the frame number that you are after.

Comment: I only render one frame at a time (it's not an animation). The "#" has to be there as it is because the images will be later on fed to another application which requires this character in filename

Comment: OK, I got the absolute folder path from that `scene.render.frame_path(scene.frame_current)` and then managed to replace the filename with the one I'm generating and now I have the full, correct path!